# Virtual Printer

Tags: printing

are there any Virtual printer in Ubuntu that can be used during development to print RAW (similar to what most Thermal printer does--but virtual), either print to file or print to display.

Answer (score 4):

You sure can, and I know of two ways to do it.

a) The CUPS drivers include a definition of a plain text printer. [Install CUPS](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/cups.html.en), configure it, then choose that printer and print.

b) RAW printing is also available as per [this link](https://qz.io/wiki/setting-up-a-raw-printer-in-ubuntu-linux), and it allows the selection of a plain text printer which is exactly what you are asking for, without the use of any driver or printing subsystem.

- Open System Settings > Printers
- Pick Add
- For the driver, choose text-only from Database > Generic > Forward
- Give it a name, and test print.